# What mean java -cp in bash and how to rewrite it in batch

Tags: bash, batch-file, jenkins, weblogic, wlst

Hello I need to write Batch script to deploy webapp to Weblogic server domain via WLST in Jenkins. In this article [Bash script to deploy webapp to Weblogic server domain via WLST](https://blogs.oracle.com/oem/bash-script-to-deploy-webapp-to-weblogic-server-domain-via-wlst-v2) written code in bash. I don't understand what mean "/usr/bin/java -cp ***.jar ... " and how to rewrite it in bath script.

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST_NAME=${1-localhost}
HOST_USER=${2-weblogic}
HOST_PASS=${3-welcome1}
HOST_PORT=${4-7001}
SCRIPT_HOME="$(dirname $(readlink -f $0))"
WL_JAR="${SCRIPT_HOME}/middleware/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/weblogic.jar"
JAM_JAR="myapp.war"

function agentDeployer()
{
 /usr/bin/java -cp ${WL_JAR} weblogic.Deployer -adminurl t3://${HOST_NAME}:${HOST_PORT} -user ${HOST_USER} -password ${HOST_PASS} -targets ${SERVER_LIST} -deploy -upload ${JAM_JAR}
}
agentDeployer
```

Comment: In a Windows batch file you need `java.exe -cp "%WL_JAR%"` best with specifying also full path to `java.exe`. `-cp` option specifies the class path(s) being the next argument. Of course the entire bash script must be converted into a Windows batch file. [SS64](https://ss64.com/) has lots of pages explaining **bash** as well as Windows **cmd**. Good luck on your bash to batch conversion task.

Comment: By the way: If you have Java installed already on Windows and its path to the executables (binaries) was added to environment variable `PATH` during installation or later by you, then you can run in a command prompt window `java.exe -?` and Windows command interpreter will find `java.exe` and execute it with argument `-?` which results in getting displayed in the window the brief help of console version of Java listing also `-cp` with a short description.

Comment: @Mofi Thank you!

Comment: Weblogic ships with a script that sets the classpath for you - called `setDomainEnv.cmd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-cp  stands for Class Path,you specify the locations of the class needed by the application 

java- cp ==>java will search to find the class files as they are needed by the program.

You don't need to rewrite in batch script, i mean the command java -cp, because it's the same.

Good Luck !!